# Unable to run the cocos2dx sample game from android studio

Tags: android, ant, cocos2d-x

I try to run the cocos2dx sample program but I get the following error Is there something wrong with the path or the setting ? I would love to hear from you!

```
Mic-no-MacBook-Pro:CocoFolder mic$ cocos run -s ~/Desktop/CocoFolder/NewGame -p android --android-studio
/Users/mic/.bash_profile: line 8: export: `PATH:/Users/mic/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/android-ndk-r14b:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin': not a valid identifier
/Users/mic/.bash_profile: line 11: export: `PATH:/Users/mic/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin:/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/android-ndk-r14b:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin': not a valid identifier
Building mode: debug
Using Android Studio project : /Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/NewGame/proj.android-studio
running: '/Users/mic/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/android update project -t android-13 -p /Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/NewGame/proj.android-studio/app'

*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "update project -t android-13 -p /Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/NewGame/proj.android-studio/app"
```

This is inside the bash profile

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant
export PATH=$ANT_HOME:$PATH

export ANT_ROOT=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mic/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk
export PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/mic/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk
export PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$PATH

export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant
export PATH=$ANT_HOME:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH

export NDK_ROOT=/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/android-ndk-r14b
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH

export COCOS2D_CONSOLE_ROOT=/Users/mic/Desktop/CocoFolder/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin

export PATH=$COCOS2D_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compile run -p android --android-studio` doesn't work because it also depends on android.bat utility.

You're using Android SDK tools build 25.3.X version and now, the android command is gone.
Android SDK tools release note [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017). The android command & ant scripts are removed.

One solution is downgrade to previous version (25.2.3) of SDK tools from this page:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html (see the bottom of the page)
and then replaced tools folder in the Android sdk with the previous one.

Another solution download [cocos2d-console](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-console) from GitHub repo (v3 branch) and extract all files and put into /cocos2d-x/tools/cocos2d-console folder after deleting old files of cocos2d-console folder.